# why does the playbook work if the wrong username is specified in the hosts file

Tags: typescript, ansible

I'm new to learning ansible, and I can't figure out why the playbook didn't give an error, even though the hosts file has the wrong name

This is my playbook

```
---
- hosts: example
  become: yes
  roles:
    - mysql-user-drop
    - mysql-db-drop
    - mysql-db-create
    - mysql-table-create
    - mysql-user-create  
  vars:
    - db_name: 'database1'
    - db_username: 'username1'
    - db_password: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=32 chars=ascii_letters') }}"
```

this is my hosts file

```
[example]
***.***.*.** ansible_port=** ansible_user=wrong_name ansible_ssh_pass=myPassword ansible_become_pass=myPassword
```

the playbook launch command

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml
```

I tried many things, I also inserted my wrong username into the playbook startup command, but it still worked and did not give errors

Comment: Probably because something else if overwriting it. To start with, print the `ansible_user` in a debug task: `- debug: var=ansible_user`.

Answer (score 0):

#### If the user `wrong_name`

- exists on your target system
- and is configured with the password “myPassword”

Then it works because Ansible can connect to the host `example`.

#### If you didn't configure the inventory in the `ansible.cfg`

You should try to reference the inventory directly in the playbook

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory
```

(https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-inventory-in-a-directory)